# index matrix in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I have a problem with angularjs and symfony2. I have a variable $scope.count and a matrix of addresses.

```
$scope.addressToAdd = {
                address: '',
                street_number: '',
                route: '',
                locality: '',
                administrative_area_level_1: '',
                country: '',
                postal_code: '',
                latitude: '',
                longitude: ''
            };
```

How can I put this values in html? if I put this {{ address[count]['address'] }} when I added a new address this value change and I want that this variable will be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

have a look at one time bindings.

use

```
{{::address[count]['address']}}
```

this will cause that the adress will not be updated again